# Actionmailer BCC not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, email, actionmailer

Does BCC not work in Rails 3?  My TO and cc work great but BCC just will not work.  I saw other people were having similar problems so I was wondering if anyone solved it.  I am using 
actionmailer (3.2.6).  Here is the code I have:

mail(:to => email_to, :from => email_from, :bcc => ["example@gmail.com"], :subject => @subject)

Comment: I have the same issue, with a similar 'mail' line.

Answer (score 0):

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html

You are doing it correctly.  Are you sure you are not using the same address in your BCC as your TO?